# Change Error localizedDescription

Tags: swift, error-reporting

I've an error class that is:

```
public enum ModelError: Error {
  case invalidArray(model: String)

  var localizedDescription: String {
    switch self {
    case .invalidArray(model: let model):
      return "\(model) has an invalid array"
    default:
      return "modelError"
    }
  }
}
```

and when passed as an `Error` in a callback function, I want to access its custom localizedDescription. For instance:

```
func report(_ error: Error) {
  print("Error report: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```

But calling `report(ModelError.invalidArray(model: "test"))` prints:

```
"The operation couldn’t be completed. (ModelError error 0.)"
```

Such things seems feasible with NSError since I can override the `localizedDescription` property there. But I don't want to use `NSError` since it's not really a swift thing and a lot of libraries work with `Error`.

Comment: Shouldn't `ModelError(model: "test")` be `ModelError.invalidArray(model: "text")` ?

Comment: yes, bad copy paste. Thanks!

Comment: I can make your code work if `ModelError` conforms to `CustomStringConvertible` and `localizeDescription` is renamed to `description`. And then print `error` instead of `error.localizedDescription`.

Comment: @rmaddy Isn't that kind of outside the bounds of CustomStringConvertible?

Comment: @PEEJWEEJ I don't know, is it? I thought that protocol can be used by anything that wants to provide a `description` method. I'm still learning Swift myself.

Comment: It can be, but the intention is that it describes the Type, not gives other info. https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/customstringconvertible the description should be something like ModelError.invalidArray(test)

Comment: but yeah, looks like this is a duplicate. Good to know

Comment: Indeed, thanks and sorry for the duplicate

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/error), localizedDescription is implemented in a protocol extension, not in the protocol declaration, which means there's nothing to adhere to or override. There is a type-wide interface for enums that adhere to Error.

My way I get around this is to use a wrapper protocol:

```
protocol LocalizedDescriptionError: Error {
    var localizedDescription: String { get }
}

public enum ModelError: LocalizedDescriptionError {
    case invalidArray(model: String)

    var localizedDescription: String {
        switch self {
        case .invalidArray(model: let model):
            return "\(model) has an invalid array"
        default:
            return "modelError"
        }
    }
}

let error: LocalizedDescriptionError = ModelError.invalidArray(model: "Model")
let text = error.localizedDescription // Model Has an invalid array
```

Comment: The above works only because you are declaring the `error` constant to be of the (specialized) `LocalizedDescriptionError` type. If you allow it to be of the (base) `Error` type, it will dispatch to the default implementation within the `Error` protocol, since - as you mentioned - `localizedDescription` is not declared within the `Error` protocol itself and thus cannot be overridden. Must use the new `LocalizedError` protocol, instead.